# Ancient lost civilization description?

Tags: history

Descriptions or list the names of ancient lost civilization of the world and specially of india?

Comment: This isn't really about Hinduism; consider adding details and asking over on [History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: research Mohenjo-Daro, Harappa, and Chanhu-Daro